# breaking a question into smaller parts

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question that I wrote here [determinant of infinitely large matrix by decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311427/determinant-of-infinitely-large-matrix-by-decomposition) that required a rather lengthy explanation. Would it be appropriate to break down that question into smaller components so it would be easier for the community to digest so it can be answered in parts? I have placed TLDR summaries in the question, but I suspect people are still repelled by the sheer length of the thing. How should I proceed?

Comment: Robert's answer is good: no reason to think a determinant can be defined for an infinite matrix.

Comment: It is, thats why I upvoted it. not quite what I'm looking for in an answer so ill leave it open for a bit.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to do that. Making questions more readable is one of the goals here. For instance, I've created a question trilogy asking about integrals over fractals, a product to evaluate said integral, and then a generalization of the problem. Those questions could go in several different tags so rather than asking it all in one post, I broker it up so the respective pros could help.